# Where can I get runkit DLL extensions for PHP 5.3+?

Tags: php, windows, runkit

That is a quick question: Where can I get PHP's runkit extension for version 5.3+? Manual for it:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php

I am searching for DLL version, as I am trying to play with it on Windows. I've searched snaps.php.net, Googled it, but no luck.

**Can you point me to the right location or upload it somewhere?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Runkit: Installation](http://de.php.net/manual/en/runkit.installation.php)

> A DLL for this PECL extension is currently unavailable. See also the [building on Windows section](http://de.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.building.php).

You have to compile the DLL yourself.

Also see https://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/pecl-binaries-on-windows/

Another option would be to use http://antecedent.github.io/patchwork

> Patchwork is a PHP library that makes it possible to redefine user-defined functions and methods at runtime, loosely replicating the functionality `runkit_function_redefine` in pure PHP 5.3 code, which, among other things, enables you to replace static and private methods with test doubles.

Comment: I know that, but maybe someone has it already compiled? I tried compiling the packages from PECL in Visual Studio, but there are errors, and I don't feel like fixing this now.

Comment: @Tomasz consider rephrasing your question title to "Can someone compile a runkit DLL for me or point me to an existing one". I've answered "how" to get a current runkit DLL.

Comment: There's no problem, Gordon - I've downloaded it from sites you've mentioned. Answer accepted, thanks. I am having an issue, when I call 'runkit_function_rename', my localhost shows "connection reset" - if I remove this line, all things work. Any suggestions?