# Can someone compile PHP runkit DLL extension for me?

Tags: php, dll, wampserver, runkit

I give up. I've asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667333/where-can-i-get-runkit-dll-extensions-for-php-5-3) some time ago but I'm again into that issue. I'm still stuck with compilation errors / missing files / other stuff that I can't / don't have time to fix. Don't get me wrong - I've compiled it several times, but none of the DLL files I've got worked. I use WAMPServer 2.1e [Apache 2.2.17, PHP 5.3.5] - after enabling php_runkit it does not start. Even already compiled DLLs from the Internet haven't worked. Another time Windows seems to be simply against me.

Now as a programmer I feel really, really lame to ask you the following: **can someone compile PHP runkit DLL extension for me or point me to the WORKING one?** Please test if it works and provide your WAMP stack configuration, so I can adjust mine.

You would be my hero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [compiled](http://nebm.ist.utl.pt/~glopes/misc/php_runkit_php5.3_nozts_vs9_Zenovich_f8daf39_patched.zip) [Zenovich's fork](https://github.com/zenovich/runkit) for 5.3, no ZTS, VS9, commit f8daf39 with trivial changes in order to build in Visual Studio.

Unfortunately, the ZTS version seems to broken and did not compile. Its problems would require some effort to fix. So you must run PHP as a CGI binary, not as an Apache module.

Comment: So you say there is no way to run it on common WAMP stack?

Comment: @Tomasz I'm saying you'll have to use CGI or FastCGI. It's not particularly difficult to configure Apache for that...

Comment: It's not good, that it cann't be "simply run" on common stack, but I'd do as you said. This is by far the best answer I was given, so no complaints from me. ;]

Comment: @Artefacto, Is the [in-built PHP webserver](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) considered TS or NTS?

Answer (score 0):

Artefacto's binaries didn't work correctly for me so I compiled the newest runkit for PHP 5.3, 5.4 and 5.5 (both TS and NTS versions). You can grab it here - https://github.com/Crack/runkit-windows.

PHP 5.3 and 5.4 modules are compiled with VC9, 5.5 with VC11 so they work with official PHP binaries.